# How many edges are in a graph $G$ such that $G-v$ is a tree $\forall v \in V(G)$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with $|V(G)| \geq 3$ such that $G-v$ is a tree $\forall v \in V(G)$. How many edges are in $G$?

---

I know that, for some $v$:

- $|E(G-v)| = |E(G)| - d(v),$
- $|V(G-v)| = |V(G)| - 1,$
- Since $G-v$ is a tree then $|E(G-v)| = |V(G-v)| - 1$.

So $\forall v \in V(G)$,

\begin{align}
|E(G)| &= |E(G-v)| + d(v),\\
&= |V(G-v)| - 1 + d(v),\\
&= |V(G)| -2 + d(v).
\end{align}

Since this is true for all vertices, then I conclude that $G$ is $k$-regular. So $k = \frac{2|E(G)|}{|V(G)|}$ and then $|E(G)| = |V(G)|$. Moreover $G$ must be a cycle.

Am I missing something? Is there some easier way to solve this?

Comment: Looks perfect to me! You could add that since $G-v$ is connected for any $v$, $G$ must also be connected, and this is why $G$ is a cycle - this rules out options like $G$ being two disconnected 3-cycles.

Comment: Depending on your definition of a tree, $G=K_2$ may also be a solution to this.

Comment: @SeanEnglish not really. It is defined that $|V(G)| \geq 3$.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I didn’t read carefully.

Answer (score 1):

We know that:

- $|E(G-v)| = |E(G)| - d(v),$
- $|V(G-v)| = |V(G)| - 1,$
- Since $G-v$ is a tree then $|E(G-v)| = |V(G-v)| - 1$.

So $\forall v \in V(G)$,

\begin{align}
|E(G)| &= |E(G-v)| + d(v),\\
&= |V(G-v)| - 1 + d(v),\\
&= |V(G)| -2 + d(v).
\end{align}

Since this is true for all vertices, then I conclude that $G$ is $k$-regular. So $k = \frac{2|E(G)|}{|V(G)|}$ and then $|E(G)| = |V(G)|$. Moreover $G$ must be a cycle.